# AJAX text input value from php function

Tags: php, ajax, input, forms

If I got something like

```
<form name="myform" method="POST"  action="">
<input type="text" name="mail">
<input type="text" name="firstname">
<input type="text" name="lastname">
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

I got a php function that returns me an array with the full name when its given the email such as:

```
function get_fullname($email){
//some code here that gives a value to $firstname, 
//$lastname, $age and $gender (for example using a cURL request)

$fullname = array(
firstname => $firstname, 
lastname=>$lastname, 
age=>$age, 
gender=>$gender);

Return $fullname;
}
```

So if, for example, my address is john.doe@gmail.com

```
$fullname['firstname'] =  "John"
$fullname['lastname'] = "Doe"
```

The question is: **How can I make those names as the `value` of my `text input` after the user as typed the email address?**

Comment: I'm reading all the answers right now. I made a simple example with name and first name but my real intend is to get a scalable code where the function could get more information from the mail (via a cURL request to a repertory for example). Thus, I'll try to look for a code that would handle that kind of informations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using jquery:

```
var email = $('input[name="mail"]'),
firstname = $('input[name="firstname"]'),
lastname = $('input[name="mailastnamel"]');

email.on('blur', function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "ajax.php",
        data: {'email': email.val()},
                type: 'post',
        success: function(result) {
        if(result.firstname && result.lastname) {
            firstname.val(result.firstname);
            lastname.val(result.lastname);
        }
    },
    dataType: 'json'
    });
});
```

create a php file called ajax.php

```
<?php
function get_fullname($email){
//some code here that gives a value to $firstname and $lastname
$fullname = array(firstname => $firstname, lastname=>$lastname)
Return $fullname
}

if(isset($_POST['email'])) {
  $fullname = get_fullname($_POST['email']);
  echo json_encode($fullname);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm... Sending the email to the PHP file:

```
function alterEmail(email){
    $.get('getName.php',
        {'email': email},
        function(data){
            names = data.split('.');
            $('.fname').html(names[0]);
            $('.lname').html(names[1]);
        }
    );
}
```

and the PHP file would look like this:

```
<?php
$splitEmail = explode('@',$_GET['email']);
echo $splitEmail[0];
?>
```

Of course, this will only work if the email looks like john.doe@gmail.com. You *could* use strictly Javascript for this, but you asked for AJAX.

Also, to use that Javascript function you can call it using onchange, something like

```
<input type="text" onchange="alterEmail(this.value);" />
```